# Adding ListBox's items to a DataTable

Tags: .net, datatable, listbox, fill

I've seen many questions here about filling a listBox using a DataTable, but is it possible to do the opposite?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this code?

```
Dim dT as New DataTable
dT.Columns.Add("Sample")
For i as Integer = 0 To lstBox.Items.Count - 1
    Dim dR as DataRow = dT.NewRow
    dR(0) = lstBox.Items(i).ToString
    dT.Rows.Add(dR)
Next
```

Comment: Ok, I think I'm figuring it out how to write it on C#. Soon I'll tell if it works or not, thanks!

Comment: I think they almost have the same commands. You're welcome. :)

Comment: Working! Used the code below:
                    dtTypeAux = new DataTable();
                    dtTypeAux.Columns.Add("TypeID");
                    foreach(object i in listBoxType.Items)
                    {
                        dtTypeAux.Rows.Add(i);
                    }

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think this sample provide you some thing useful ....

```
DataTable sampledt = new DataTable();
        DataColumn sampleColumn = new DataColumn("Col1", typeof(string));
        sampledt.Columns.Add(sampleColumn);

        foreach (object item in listBox1.Items)
        {
            sampledt.Rows.Add(item);
        }
        int _datatable_rowCount = sampledt.Rows.Count;
```